# C# Mostrar en el DataGridView el registro que se va insertarndo en la base de datos

Tags: c#

Estoy usando MySQL para el almacenamiento de datos y C# para la creación del sistema mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo mas de 1000 registros en MySQL estos los muestro en un DataGridView al momento de insertar otro y mostrarlo en el DataGridView solamente quiero que cargue el nuevo que agregue aparte de los 1000 que ya tengo, que tendría que hacer para evitar tener que consultar toda la tabla ya que esto no es óptimo porque tendría que cargar de nuevo los 1000 registros aparte del nuevo que e insertado.

El codigo que tengo para mostrar en el DataGritView es el siguiente

```
 public void MostrarAlumno(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        using (var connection = GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = "Alumnos_Mostrar_Tabla";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                MySqlDataReader leer = command.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable tabla = new DataTable();
                tabla.Load(leer);
                dgv.DataSource = tabla;
                dgv.Columns[0].Width = 330;
                dgv.Columns[1].Width = 90;
                dgv.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                dgv.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Institución";
                dgv.Columns[2].Width = 360;
                dgv.Columns[3].Width = 98;
                dgv.Columns[3].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
                dgv.Columns[3].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            }
        }
    }
```

El procemiento Alumnos_Mostrar_tabla es el siguiente

```
select  CONCAT(alumnos.NomAlumno, " ", alumnos.ApellidoPaterno, " ", alumnos.ApellidoMaterno) AS 'Nombre', 
    instituciones.Clave AS 'Institución', 
    carreras_universitarias.Carrera, 
    alumnos.Turno
    from alumnos
    inner join instituciones on instituciones.idInstitucion = 
    alumnos.idInstitucion
    inner join carreras_universitarias on carreras_universitarias.idCarrera = alumnos.idCarrera
```

Todo esto en base a las tablas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Gracias!!

Comment: Bienvenido Tony, por curiosidad, ¿Has visto la documentación del DataGridView en la MSDN?

Comment: Si, he estado buscando en la documentación pero no he podido encontrar algo referente a eso..

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, agrega el código que tienes, el que has intentado y pega los enlaces que has seguido :D

Comment: listo ya puse el codigo que muestra los regisros y el procedimiento

Comment: muestra tu codigo donde estas insertando y donde cargas por primera vez el Datagrid